# Process.StartInfo.FileName with Apostrophe

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I hope this is a simple one. Here's what I'm doing:

```
Process process = new Process {
    StartInfo = {
        FileName = "C:\\David's Program\\program.exe",
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    }
};
process.Start();
```

The problem is the `FileName` has an apostrophe, which results in:

```
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:\David's Program\program.exe'…
```

I have tested this code with `FileName` at `C:\\Davids Program\\program.exe` (no apostrophe) and there's no exception. Also, setting `UseShellExecute = true` (and not attempting to redirect standard output) while using a `FileName` with an apostrophe also works fine.

So `UseShellExecute = false` and the apostrophe in the `FileName` is definitely to blame. But, for the life of me I can't figure out how to escape it. I've tried `\'`, `\\'`, `\\\'`, and `\\\\'` all to no avail.

Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT**: I am working in a Mono 2.6 (approximate .NET 2.6 parity) environment.

**EDIT 2**: Other attempts which produce the same exception:

1. `"\"C:\\David's Program\\program.exe\""`
2. `@"C:\David's Program\program.exe"`
3. `String.Format("C:\\David{0}s Program\\program.exe", (char)39)`

I have also tested with different .exes in different locations, and in every test instance I have renamed the containing directories to remove apostrophes only to find the code then run perfectly.

Comment: Did you try `FileName = "\"C:/David's Program/program.exe\""`?

Comment: Guess you simply need to wrap the filename in double quotes like `FileName = "\"C:\\David's Program\\program.exe\""`

Comment: Process process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = {
                    FileName = @"C:\Test's\test.bat",
                    //CreateNoWindow = true,
                    //RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false
                }
            };
            process.Start(); // No problem and exception

Comment: @RenéVogt sadly that's not the answer. Same exception.

Comment: @ZayLau sorry, don't know what to say. Using `@"C:\David's Program\program.exe"` is also giving me the exception. For what it's worth, I am working in a Mono 2.6 (approximate .NET 2.6 parity) environment. I will edit the question to include this.

Comment: How about `String.Format("C:\\David{0}s Program\\program.exe", (char)39)`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett yep, same exception unfortunately.

Comment: @saarrrr interesting! But, unfortunately, no, same exception. :¬(

Comment: Nothing special about a single quote on Windows.  However it is a big deal on Unix, its shell does not like it much.  You'd have to dig through Mono source to see what it might be doing.  First try setting ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false for a possible quick fix.

Comment: @HansPassant Setting UseShellExecute = true does avoid the exception, as I mentioned in the question. Unfortunately, it also means CreateNoWindow is ignored, resulting in an ugly console window flashing on top of my application. It's kind of a deal-breaker. Thanks, though.